# The requested database 'abc' is not defined in configuration

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I create a new console application with using C# and then added my dll to my project's references. My dll has a DB class which has static properties.

```
 public class DB
 {
     public static Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionStringName");

 }
```

When DB class's properties call, it throw an exception that is 'The requested database (Connection String Name) is not defined in configuration.'
I can't create connection, so i can't get fields that i want to see its value.

What can i do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the configuration for the app - does it have a ConnectionStrings section?

Comment: Have you checked the name of the database in your configuration is spelt correctly and does indeed exist on the server specified in your connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that the ConnectionString should be placed in the app.config of the soloution that is calling the class library (.dll). Source: http://vstoolsforum.com/blogs/vbnet/archive/2009/02/20/the-requested-database-xyz-is-not-defined-in-configuration.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think it will help you out because i was having the same problem so i figure it out with this.
write code

**Database db = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);**   instead of

**Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(connectionString);**

Thanks